# How to change array elements with if/else

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, phpfox

How to change the value in array with if/else?

CODE:

```
    public function getActions()
{
    return array(
    'dislike' => array(
        'enabled' => true,
        'action_type_id' => 2,
        'phrase' => Phpfox::getPhrase('like.dislike'),
        'phrase_in_past_tense' => 'disliked',
        'item_phrase' => 'comment',
        'item_type_id' => 'feed',
        'table' => 'feed_comment',
        'column_update' => 'total_dislike',
        'column_find' => 'feed_comment_id',
        'where_to_show' => array('', 'photo')           
        )
    );
}
```

How to insert code for change with if/else?

```
if (Phpfox::isMobile())
    {
        'phrase' => Phpfox::getPhrase('mobiletemplate.unlike_icon'),
    }
else
    {
        'phrase' => Phpfox::getPhrase('like.dislike'),
    }
```

Thank you for help me!

Comment: `'phrase' =>  Phpfox::getPhrase(Phpfox::isMobile() ? 'mobiletemplate.unlike_icon' : 'like.dislike')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this logical problem with the use of the ternary operator:

```
'phrase' => Phpfox::isMobile() ? Phpfox::getPhrase('mobiletemplate.unlike_icon') : Phpfox::getPhrase('like.dislike'),
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the ternary operator to do an inline check:

```
public function getActions()
{
    return array(
    'dislike' => array(
        'enabled' => true,
        'action_type_id' => 2,
        'phrase' => Phpfox::getPhrase(
            Phpfox::isMobile()
            ? 'mobiletemplate.unlike_icon'
            : 'like.dislike'
        ),
        'phrase_in_past_tense' => 'disliked',
        'item_phrase' => 'comment',
        'item_type_id' => 'feed',
        'table' => 'feed_comment',
        'column_update' => 'total_dislike',
        'column_find' => 'feed_comment_id',
        'where_to_show' => array('', 'photo')           
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplier, but just for this case:

```
'phrase' => Phpfox::getPhrase(Phpfox::isMobile()? 'mobiletemplate.unlike_icon' : 'like.dislike'),
```

Answer (score -3):

Somthing like this

```
'phrase' => call_user_func(function(){ 
   if(Phpfox::isMobile()){
      return Phpfox::getPhrase('mobiletemplate.unlike_icon');
   }else{
      return Phpfox::getPhrase('like.dislike');
   }
 }), ...
```

Comment: Why would you add an anonymous function to the array?

Comment: Sorry guys why this rush? It's not a race! IMHO anonymous function are more flexible than ternary operator.

Comment: I request to all of you to remove your own downvote. My code perfectly answer to the question and shows an alternative way to solve this issue. Your downvote was based on a minor error code - fixed in a minute - and now is obsolete. Thank you.